# Shiny app does not reproduce graphics and not is responsive

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shiny-server

I'm building a shiny application ([Here!](https://fsbmat.shinyapps.io/Corona/)), Whose code below and the database for compilation can be found on my [github](https://github.com/fsbmat-ufv/fsbmat-ufv.github.io/tree/master/blog_posts/26-03-2020/Corona). I can't understand why the graphics "Number of Deaths by Covid19 in Brazil" and "Number of Confirmed with Covid19 in Brazil" are not compiling? On my computer, sometimes the graphics are generated, sometimes not! In addition, the renderText () function is also not working and the graphics do not respond when changing the choice of state?

Obs: We did not notice an error when the code size decreased and only kept the graphics that are not compiling with the code below. That is, apparently, the brilliant cannot compile all the graphics for some reason!

Here is the code I am using:

Minimal code (I don't see the error in this case):

```
library("shiny")
library("readr")
library("dplyr")
library("tidyverse")
library("treemap")
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")
library("hrbrthemes")
library("ggrepel")
library("shinythemes")
library("rio")
library(miceadds)
load(url("https://rawcdn.githack.com/fsbmat-ufv/fsbmat-ufv.github.io/a16ef0fe0a27374cdbb7f88106c080ca0cd2ded3/blog_posts/26-03-2020/Corona/covid19.RData"))
data <- x
rm(x)


data$deaths[is.na(data$deaths)] <- 0
data$date <- as.Date(data$date)
data <- data[order(data$date) , ]

data <- data %>%
  dplyr::filter(place_type == "state") %>%
  dplyr::group_by(state,date, confirmed,deaths) %>% 
  select(date, state, confirmed, deaths, estimated_population_2019)
names(data) <- c("date", "state", "confirmed", "deaths", "Pop")

aggSetor <-data%>%filter(date==last(data$date))%>%group_by(state) %>% summarise(quantidade = sum(deaths), 
                                                                                confirmedM = mean(confirmed))
aggSetor$escala <- scale(aggSetor$confirmedM) 

ui <- fluidPage(  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Coronavirus in Brazil"),


  fluidRow(
    column(width = 4, class = "well",
           h4("Number of Deaths by Covid19 in Brazil"),
           plotOutput("plot1", height = 200,
                      dblclick = "plot1_dblclick",
                      brush = brushOpts(
                        id = "plot1_brush",
                        resetOnNew = TRUE
                      )
           )
    ),
    column(width = 4, class = "well",
           h4("Number of Confirmed with Covid19 in Brazil"),
           plotOutput("plot2", height = 200,
                      dblclick = "plot2_dblclick",
                      brush = brushOpts(
                        id = "plot2_brush",
                        resetOnNew = TRUE
                      )
           )
    ),
    column(width = 4, class = "well",
           h4("Treemap of deaths and number of confirmed by State"),
           plotOutput("plot3", height = 200,
                      dblclick = "plot3_dblclick",
                      brush = brushOpts(
                        id = "plot3_brush",
                        resetOnNew = TRUE
                      )
           )
    )

  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {


  filt <- selectInput("codeInput",label ="Escolha um Estado",
                      choices = as.list(unique(data$state)))

  output$codePanel <- renderUI({ filt

  })

  dataset<-reactive({ 

    subset(data, state == input$codeInput)  

  })



  dataset2<-reactive({
    df <- dataset()
    teste1 <- dplyr::lag(df$deaths)
    teste1[is.na(teste1)] <- 0
    teste2 <- dplyr::lag(df$confirmed)
    teste2[is.na(teste2)] <- 0
    df$teste1 <- teste1
    df$teste2 <- teste2
    df$deaths_day <- df$deaths-df$teste1
    df$confirmed_day <- df$confirmed-df$teste2
    df <- df %>% select(1:5,8:9)
    return(df)
  })

  dataset3 <- reactive({
    ndeaths <- data %>% group_by(date) %>% summarise(deaths = sum(deaths))
    return(ndeaths)
  })

  dataset4 <- reactive({
    nconfirmed <- data %>% group_by(date) %>% summarise(confirmed = sum(confirmed))
    return(nconfirmed)
  })


  # -------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Single zoomable plot (on left)
  #ranges <- reactiveValues(x = date, y = confirmed)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    xlab <- "Data"
    legenda <- "fonte: https://brasil.io/dataset/covid19"

    ggplot2::ggplot(dataset3(), aes(x = date, y = deaths)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", alpha = .7, color = "red", fill = "red") +
      scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day",
                   date_labels = "%d/%m") +
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, max(dataset3()$deaths+20, na.rm = TRUE) + 3),
                         expand = c(0, 0)) +
      geom_text(aes(label=deaths), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25) +
      labs(x = xlab,
           y = "Number of Deaths",
           title = " ",
           caption = legenda) +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(axis.text.x =  element_text(angle = 90))
  })



  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    xlab <- "Data"
    legenda <- "fonte: https://brasil.io/dataset/covid19/caso"
    ggplot2::ggplot(dataset4(), aes(x = date, y = confirmed)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", alpha = .7, color = "red", fill = "red") +
      scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day",
                   date_labels = "%d/%m") +
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, max(dataset4()$confirmed+300, na.rm = TRUE) + 3),
                         expand = c(0, 0)) +
      geom_text(aes(label=confirmed), position=position_dodge(width=0.5), vjust=-0.25) +
      labs(x = xlab,
           y = "Number of Confirmed",
           title = " ",
           caption = legenda) +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(axis.text.x =  element_text(angle = 90))
  })

  output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
    treemap(aggSetor, index = "state", vSize = "quantidade", vColor = "escala",
            type = "value", palette = "-RdGy", lowerbound.cex.labels = 0.3,
            title  =  "Color related to deaths - Size related to confirmed")
  })



}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Complete code:

```
library("shiny")
library("readr")
library("dplyr")
library("tidyverse")
library("treemap")
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")
library("hrbrthemes")
library("ggrepel")
library("shinythemes")
library("rio")
#library(miceadds)
#setwd("~/GitHub/fsbmat-ufv.github.io/blog_posts/26-03-2020/Shiny/Corona")
#data <- read_csv(url("https://rawcdn.githack.com/fsbmat-ufv/fsbmat-ufv.github.io/fcba93f491ed21eba0628471649eb9a5bda033f2/blog_posts/26-03-2020/Corona/covid19.csv"))
#export(data, "covid19.rdata")
load(url("https://rawcdn.githack.com/fsbmat-ufv/fsbmat-ufv.github.io/a16ef0fe0a27374cdbb7f88106c080ca0cd2ded3/blog_posts/26-03-2020/Corona/covid19.RData"))
#load("covid19.Rdata")
data <- x
rm(x)
#data <- miceadds::load.Rdata2(filename=url("https://rawcdn.githack.com/fsbmat-ufv/fsbmat-ufv.github.io/a16ef0fe0a27374cdbb7f88106c080ca0cd2ded3/blog_posts/26-03-2020/Corona/covid19.RData"))


data$deaths[is.na(data$deaths)] <- 0
data$date <- as.Date(data$date)
data <- data[order(data$date) , ]

data <- data %>%
  dplyr::filter(place_type == "state") %>%
  dplyr::group_by(state,date, confirmed,deaths) %>% 
  select(date, state, confirmed, deaths, estimated_population_2019)
names(data) <- c("date", "state", "confirmed", "deaths", "Pop")

aggSetor <-data%>%filter(date==last(data$date))%>%group_by(state) %>% summarise(quantidade = sum(deaths), 
                                                                                confirmedM = mean(confirmed))
aggSetor$escala <- scale(aggSetor$confirmedM) 

#tabPanelSobre <- source("sobre.r")$value

ui <- fluidPage(#theme=shinytheme("united"),
                headerPanel(
                  HTML(
                    '<div id="stats_header">
            Coronavirus in Brazil
            <a href="https://maf105.github.io/" target="_blank"><img align="right" alt="fsbmat Logo" src="./img/fsbmat.png" /></a>
            </div>'
                  ),
                  "Coronavirus in Brazil"
                ),
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Coronavirus in Brazil"),
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("codePanel")#,
      #tags$p("Autor: Fernando de Souza Bastos - Professor da Universidade Federal de Vicosa - MG")
    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      # Output: Formatted text for caption ----
      h3(textOutput("caption")),

      # Output: 1 ----
      plotOutput("deathsPlot", height = 300,
                 dblclick = "deathsPlot_dblclick",
                 brush = brushOpts(
                   id = "deathsPlot_brush",
                   resetOnNew = TRUE
                 )
      ),

      plotOutput("confirmedPlot", height = 300,
                 dblclick = "confirmedPlot_dblclick",
                 brush = brushOpts(
                   id = "confirmedPlot_brush",
                   resetOnNew = TRUE
                 )
      ),

      plotOutput("dayPlot", height = 300,
                 dblclick = "dayPlot_dblclick",
                 brush = brushOpts(
                   id = "dayPlot_brush",
                   resetOnNew = TRUE
                 )
      ),

      DT::dataTableOutput("text")

    )




  ),

  fluidRow(
    column(width = 4, class = "well",
           h4("Number of Deaths by Covid19 in Brazil"),
           plotOutput("plot1", height = 200,
                      dblclick = "plot1_dblclick",
                      brush = brushOpts(
                        id = "plot1_brush",
                        resetOnNew = TRUE
                      )
           )
    ),
    column(width = 4, class = "well",
           h4("Number of Confirmed with Covid19 in Brazil"),
           plotOutput("plot2", height = 200,
                      dblclick = "plot2_dblclick",
                      brush = brushOpts(
                        id = "plot2_brush",
                        resetOnNew = TRUE
                      )
           )
    ),
    column(width = 4, class = "well",
           h4("Treemap of deaths and number of confirmed by State"),
           plotOutput("plot3", height = 200,
                      dblclick = "plot3_dblclick",
                      brush = brushOpts(
                        id = "plot3_brush",
                        resetOnNew = TRUE
                      )
           )
    )

  )#,
  #tabPanelSobre()
)

server <- function(input, output) {


  filt <- selectInput("codeInput",label ="Escolha um Estado",
                      choices = as.list(unique(data$state)))

  output$codePanel <- renderUI({ filt

  })

  dataset<-reactive({ 

    subset(data, state == input$codeInput)  

  })



  dataset2<-reactive({
    df <- dataset()
    teste1 <- dplyr::lag(df$deaths)
    teste1[is.na(teste1)] <- 0
    teste2 <- dplyr::lag(df$confirmed)
    teste2[is.na(teste2)] <- 0
    df$teste1 <- teste1
    df$teste2 <- teste2
    df$deaths_day <- df$deaths-df$teste1
    df$confirmed_day <- df$confirmed-df$teste2
    df <- df %>% select(1:5,8:9)
    return(df)
  })

  dataset3 <- reactive({
    ndeaths <- data %>% group_by(date) %>% summarise(deaths = sum(deaths))
    return(ndeaths)
  })

  dataset4 <- reactive({
    nconfirmed <- data %>% group_by(date) %>% summarise(confirmed = sum(confirmed))
    return(nconfirmed)
  })

  # output$caption and output$mpgPlot functions
  formulaText <- reactive({
    paste("Results Regarding the State of", input$codeInput)
  })

  # Return the formula text for printing as a caption ----
  output$caption <- renderText({
    formulaText()
  })

  output$text<-renderDataTable(dataset())

  # # Generate a plot of the requested variable against mpg ----
  # # and only exclude outliers if requested
    output$deathsPlot <- renderPlot({
      xlab <- "Data"
      legenda <- "fonte: https://brasil.io/dataset/covid19/caso"

      ggplot2::ggplot(dataset(), aes(x = date, y = deaths)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity", alpha = .7, color = "red", fill = "red") +
        scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day",
                     date_labels = "%d/%m") +
        scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, max(dataset()$deaths+20, na.rm = TRUE) + 3),
                           expand = c(0, 0)) +
        geom_text(aes(label=deaths), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25) +
        labs(x = xlab,
             y = "Numbers of Deaths",
             title = "Number of deaths by COVID-19",
             caption = legenda) +
        theme_minimal() +
        theme(axis.text.x =  element_text(angle = 90))

    })


  output$confirmedPlot <- renderPlot({
    xlab <- "Data"
    legenda <- "fonte: https://brasil.io/dataset/covid19/caso"

    ggplot2::ggplot(dataset(), aes(x = date, y = confirmed)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", alpha = .7, color = "red", fill = "red") +
      scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day",
                   date_labels = "%d/%m") +
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, max(dataset()$confirmed+100, na.rm = TRUE) + 3),
                         expand = c(0, 0)) +
      geom_text(aes(label=confirmed), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25) +
      labs(x = xlab,
           y = "Numbers of Confirmed",
           title = "Number of Cases Confirmed with Covid19",
           caption = legenda) +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(axis.text.x =  element_text(angle = 90))

    })


  output$dayPlot <- renderPlot({
    xlab <- "Data"
    legenda <- "fonte: https://brasil.io/dataset/covid19/caso"

    #Graph with the number of confirmed daily cases
    ggplot(dataset2(), aes(x=date, y=confirmed_day))+
      geom_line( color="steelblue")+ 
      geom_point() + 
      geom_text_repel(aes(label=confirmed_day), size = 3)+
      xlab("Data") + ylab("Number of confirmed daily cases")+
      theme_ipsum() +
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1))+
      scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 day", date_labels = "%d %b")




  })


  # -------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Single zoomable plot (on left)
  #ranges <- reactiveValues(x = date, y = confirmed)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    xlab <- "Data"
    legenda <- "fonte: https://brasil.io/dataset/covid19"

    ggplot2::ggplot(dataset3(), aes(x = date, y = deaths)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", alpha = .7, color = "red", fill = "red") +
      scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day",
                   date_labels = "%d/%m") +
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, max(dataset3()$deaths+20, na.rm = TRUE) + 3),
                         expand = c(0, 0)) +
      geom_text(aes(label=deaths), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25) +
      labs(x = xlab,
           y = "Number of Deaths",
           title = " ",
           caption = legenda) +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(axis.text.x =  element_text(angle = 90))
  })

  # -------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Linked plots (middle and right)
  #ranges2 <- reactiveValues(x = NULL, y = NULL)

  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    xlab <- "Data"
    legenda <- "fonte: https://brasil.io/dataset/covid19/caso"
    ggplot2::ggplot(dataset4(), aes(x = date, y = confirmed)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", alpha = .7, color = "red", fill = "red") +
      scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day",
                   date_labels = "%d/%m") +
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, max(dataset4()$confirmed+300, na.rm = TRUE) + 3),
                         expand = c(0, 0)) +
      geom_text(aes(label=confirmed), position=position_dodge(width=0.5), vjust=-0.25) +
      labs(x = xlab,
           y = "Number of Confirmed",
           title = " ",
           caption = legenda) +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(axis.text.x =  element_text(angle = 90))
  })

  output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
    treemap(aggSetor, index = "state", vSize = "quantidade", vColor = "escala",
            type = "value", palette = "-RdGy", lowerbound.cex.labels = 0.3,
            title  =  "Color related to deaths - Size related to confirmed")
  })



}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Voted to close.

Comment: Could you say what the problem is with the question?

Comment: While it may be a reproducible example, it certainly is not minimal...

Comment: My friend, there is no way to put a smaller example, my problem is in this code. The minimal example is not always possible. Here is a help site, my graphics have this objective, I had hours of work to produce this application, don't be intolerant!

Comment: I agree with @cory, your code is quite long. For example, you say your problem is that graphics do not compile, then maybe you could remove all the parts of your code where you import and treat your data (which are not necessary if the problem is in the graphics part). Just use `dput` on your clean data and put the result in your post. This way, it does not take much place and we see what your data looks like. You can also remove some comments or the lines in your plots that are not really useful (title, labels, etc.). It may seem not much but you can really simplify your example by doint this

Comment: Also you can add the error message if there is one

Comment: I put a minimum code. In this case, I don't see any errors, as I said in the question, the problem is in the complete code. I don't understand why. Shiny application codes are large and often complex, so it's difficult to send a question where the code doesn't need a scroll bar!

Comment: @bretauv I don't get any error messages, the code compiles without error, however, the graphics are not generated when I store the application on shinyapps.io.

Comment: since you download your data every time you launch the app, it may take some time to import. Did you try waiting some time when the shiny app is running to see if it is not just because your internet connection has ups and downs?

Comment: Thanks @bretauv, Yes, I thought that could be it, however, after minutes of waiting, the graphics are not generated. In addition, when modifying the choice of the State, very few times the graphs change. I believe the problem is really something related to the communication between the database import and the application codes. So, I created a .Rdata and put it on github, even so, I continue to observe the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the problem is the communication of shiny with the database. The same application using Fleshboard worked perfectly, follow the link for viewing, [click here!](https://fsbmat.shinyapps.io/CoronaBR/#section-page-1)